# Не получается передать число во фрагмент

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, fragment-manager

Запуск фрагмента:

```
val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putInt("position", position)
fragment.setArguments(bundle)

val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
activity.supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
    .commitNow()
```

Попытка получить переданное число в запущенном фрагменте:

```
val position: Int = getArguments()?.getInt("position", 0) ?: 0
```

Проблема в том, что `position` всегда оказывается равно значению по умолчанию - то есть 0.

Comment: Где вы объявили val position? Если в теле класса фрагмента, то аргументы на момент инициализации переменной еще не назначены вами. Перенесите инициализацию переменной в любой метод жизненного цикла

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где вы объявили val position? Если в теле класса фрагмента, то аргументы на момент инициализации переменной еще не назначены вами.

Перенесите инициализацию переменной в любой метод жизненного цикла